# Material Design's 500 colors not enough contrast with white

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I tried Android Studio's Theme Editor today and got some warnings from it.

[image: material color not enough contrast]

According to the material design guidelines, I should use 500 as the primary colors but why is that the Theme Editor says that my primary color (Material Light Blue 500) doesn't have enough contrast with my textColorPrimary(#ffffff)? I also think that by not having the correct colors, my app title gets a black color on the recent apps screen which should be white.

[image]

Comment: Use 500 and 800 color code, warning will remove.

Answer (score 0):

The text color in Recent apps gets computed automatically from background. The same algorithm is used to generate the warning in theme editor. When you look at the [Light Blue 500 color](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette) you see Google suggests using black text over it.

You're free to use white text color in your app despite the warning but you can't change the Recent apps screen behavior.

Comment: I tried using Material Blue 500 and Light Blue 600, it also says not enough contrast.