# How to resolve theme warning in default Android Material Design project in Android Studio 1.4?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I'm trying new **sample project** with **Android Material Design** on **Android Studio 1.4**.

I created a **project** with an **Empty Activity** :

[image: Creation Project withEmpty Activity]

Everything works fine. However, from the beginning, we can notice that there are **warnings** at the **Theme Editor**:

**1) Warning** in `ColorPrimary`:

> Not enough contrast with not enable **textColorPrimary** and default
>   **textColorPrimary**

**2) Warning** in `android:textColorPrimary`:

> Not enough contrast with **colorPrimary**

[image: Theme Editor]

My question is simple: **How to resolve warnings?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33058741/4596556 Please check once.

Comment: show your color xml file

Comment: Given [the roster of outstanding bugs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=theme+editor&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles), it would appear that the theme editor is not ready for serious use yet.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare I hope there is going to be an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Android Studio 1.4, but I can click the color box besides the warning to see the contrast problem on Android Studio 2.0.

Choose another color from the color gradient panel until the warning disappears.

[image: gradient panel]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the same color i.e. `@color/colorPrimary` `(#FF3F51B5)` as in your case, then just **change the** **Theme Parent** from `AppCompact Light` (current) to `AppCompact Dark`

This will solve your problem.

*In case if you want to choose some other color you can always twist around theme parent from dark to light or light to dark.*

*If you still did not get your choice result then the only option is to choose lighter color so that it can match contrast value with the theme.*

Hope this helps.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

the 2 cross in my case, one the colorprimary says it doesn't have enough contrast with textcolorprimary, and vise versa.

And i think it says the amount of contrast between the background, and the text, is not enough to be easily visible to the user, and the one who wrote the error, just didn't knew how to express it...